# c# wpf update Mainwindowfrom another project

Tags: c#, wpf

i am a little in trouble with a C# WPF Project, using a Mainwindow for the GUI and an other project for the Busines logic (doing the tasks).
The MainWindow is the start project and i referenced here the BusinesLogic Project.  After clicking a button, I start doing the needed tasks.
But i am not able to update the GUI while running tasks in the BusinesLogic project. A reference back is not possible.

What I have to do to update the GUI of the Mainwindow from the BusinesLogic project?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have a look on MVVM (Model View ViewModel) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up on [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx) (Model View ViewModel) and implementing it into your project. It is designed to work with WPF applications and supports the separation of the View and Model but provides binding between the two to update the UI from the Logic.